# Datamax DPL Chinese characters printing

Tags: printing, fonts, character

I'm trying to print this text "简体字" on an example label using bartender and sending DPL code generated printing to file.

The output i got of the text field is

```
1911UC001310051P010P010¼òÌå×Ö
```

In the documentation i found the example

```
1911UC002650150P012P012<BD><D0>A1><A1><A1><A1><BD><D1><A1><A1><A1><A1><BD><D2><A1><A1>
<A1><A1><BD><D3><00><00><CR>
```

the < XX > fields are hex.

I used a native GB chinese font, that's enabled on the printer and set on the DPL by the command yUGB.

What am i doing wrong?